# progressive dinner

Tags: combinatorics

I want to have a progressive dinner with 3 courses and each couple will host one course. Each course should have a unique group of couples so that during the evening no two couples are ever at more than one course together but all couples are at one course with each of the other couples. How many couples will this work for and how would they be grouped for each course?

Comment: What have you tried?  I find a solution with rather few couples, so just playing will get you there.

Comment: I was thinking of 16 couples but can't make the numbers work so that each couple has one course with all of the rest of the couples but only one course.

Comment: Google 'progressive party problem'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution with three couples.  Have AB, BC, AC at the three courses.  Otherwise, you can have all the couples to one course and a single couple (presumably the hosts) to the other two.

To prove these are all the solutions, at least two of the courses are each missing at least one couple.  If they weren't you would have two courses with all the couples and everybody would meet everybody at least twice.  If A is missing from two courses, everybody must be at the third to meet A.  Then no pair can dine together at either of the other two.  If the couple missing from the two courses differs, call one A and the other B.  For A to dine with B they must both be at the third course.  Now if any other couple is not at the third course, they must be at both the first and second to get both A and B.  It can't be more than one, because then they would meet twice.

Comment: But I need it for many more than 3 couples - I was thinking 12 - 18 couples!

Comment: If the number of couples were divisible by $3$, you could use this solution, just dividing the couples into $3$ even groups, $A$, $B$, anc $C$. Then they could co-host or... something.

Comment: Then unless you change the rules you have to have them all to one course.  The easiest thing is to have more courses.  You get a lot more freedom with more courses.

Comment: @Meelo: No, because the people in a group would eat together twice

Comment: Would it work with 4 courses and 16 couples?

Comment: No, try filling in a table and you'll get stuck early.  For $16$ couples there are $\frac12\cdot 16 \cdot 15=120$ pairs.  If you have six couples to a course, you cover $15$ per course, so you might be able to do it with eight courses.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 9 couples labelled S1,S2,S3, M1, M2, M3 and D1, D2 and D3

Starter Course hosted as follows:-

S1 hosts M1 and D1,
S2 hosts M2 and D2,
S3 hosts M3 and D3,

Main Course hosted as follows:
M1 hosts S2 and D3,
M2 hosts S3 and D1,
M3 hosts S1 and D2,

Dessert hosted as follows:
D1 hosts S2 and M3,
D2 hosts S3 and M1,
D3 hosts S1 and M2